# Arrow not showing in pandas plot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TwK4I.png)I need an arrow in my plot, I tried to put in in but it won't show. I researched and could not find what I did wrong.

```
ax_google = df_stocks['GOOG'].plot(linewidth=5, color= "k", figsize=(9, 6))
ax_google.set_title("GOOGLE prices development", size=16, weight='bold')
ax_google.set_xlabel('Date')
ax_google.set_ylabel("Index")
ax_google.legend(['GOOG'])
ax_google.set_ylim(0,400)
ax_google.set_xlim('2008-01-01', '2010-01-01');
arrow = {'facecolor':'black', 'width':2, 'shrink':0.05}
ax.annotate('Bankruptcy of Lehman Brothers', xy=('2008-09-15',245), xytext=('2009-06-06',325), arrowprops=arrow);
```

Comment: Can you include the plot you are getting and show where you want the arrow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell from your code is that it seems you haven't set axes.

Axes are kind of frames on a figure. You can find an image on [Matplotlib website](https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/introductory/usage.html).
However, you need to create a subplot with:

```
fig, ax_google = plt.subplots(figsize=(9,6)) #using ax_google instead of ax
ax_google.plot("GOOG",data=df_stocks,linewidth=5, color= "k")
```

and then continue your code.

I cannot check if this works because I don't have the data.
Hope this helps.